# In puremvc, how to wait for sendNotification/notifyObservers finishes

Tags: actionscript, puremvc

In PureMVC / ActionScript, after sending out notifications using send Notification or notify-observers, how do I make sure all the observers has received the notification and finished the work?

On the other words, is sendNotification in synchronized way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the proper way to do this is to put all of your tasks in [SimpleCommand](http://puremvc.org/pages/docs/AS3/multicore/framework_asdoc/org/puremvc/as3/multicore/patterns/command/SimpleCommand.html)s, and then add all of these to a single [MacroCommand](http://puremvc.org/pages/docs/AS3/multicore/framework_asdoc/org/puremvc/as3/multicore/patterns/command/MacroCommand.html).  As long as the SimpleCommands are synchronous (eg, you don't start any load processes), when the MacroCommand finished, you are guaranteed that all of the SimpleCommands in it have finished.

You may also want to investigate the [AsyncCommand](http://trac.puremvc.org/Utility_AS3_AsyncCommand) utility.  I am not a huge fan of this, but some of my colleagues like it.